# Connect to Object Server error when using Realm Browser to connect to Object Server

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am following the [Getting started guide](https://realm.io/docs/realm-mobile-platform/get-started/) for the Realm Mobile Platform. I started the Realm Object server and run the Mac OSX demo task app. I cannot however connect to the object server using the Mac OSX Realm Browser app.

I open the Realm Browser and select `Connect to Object Server`. I enter `realm://127.0.0.1:9080` as the server url and then paste in the long token string ending in == that I get from terminal when I started the Object server with the command `start-object-server.command`. I now click connect and get the following error:

```
Failed to connect to Object Server.
Check the url and that the server is accessible.
```

In terminal I see a log saying that I need to login to `http://127.0.0.1:27080/` and create an admin user. I navigate to that url and can see my user which is an admin.

Here are the logs:

```
info: Logging to console at level 'info'.
info: Realm Object Server sync server listening on 127.0.0.1:27800.
info: Realm Object Server web server listening on 127.0.0.1:27080.
info: http proxy listening on 0.0.0.0:9080.
info: sync-server: Realm sync server started ([realm-core-2.0.0], [realm-sync-1.0.0-BETA-1.0])
info: sync-server: Directory holding persistent state: /Users/grant/Apps/realm-mobile-platform/realm-object-server/object-server/root_dir/user_data
info: sync-server: Listening on 127.0.0.1:27800 (sync protocol version 14)
info: The Realm Object Server requires an initial admin user to start. To continue, please open your web browser to access the dashboard at: http://127.0.0.1:27080 and register your user.
info: sync-server: Connection[1]: Connection from 127.0.0.1:53352
info: sync-server: Connection[1]: Received: CLIENT(protocol_version=14, client_info_size=2, client_info = {})
info: sync-server: Connection[1]: Session[1]: Initiated
info: sync-server: Connection[1]: Session[1]: Received: BIND(server_path='/__admin', signed_user_token=eyJpZGVudGl0eSI6ImF1..., need_file_ident_pair=0)
info: sync-server: Connection[1]: Session[1]: Received: IDENT(server_file_ident=80096, client_file_ident=1, client_file_ident_secret=523599, scan_server_version=13, scan_client_version=24, latest_server_version=13, latest_server_session_ident=7426485)
```

When I run `telnet localhost 9080` I get the following output:

```
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Any idea why I cannot connect to the object server using the Mac OSX Realm Browser app?

Comment: Is the server actually listening on that port? Could you verify with either a `telnet localhost 9080` or some `netstat` foo?

Comment: @teotwaki thanks, I have added the telnet logs.

Comment: I re-downloaded the latest Realm files and everything works as expected now.

Answer (score 1):

I re-downloaded the latest Realm files and everything works as expected now.